# how to take screen shot using ASL library?

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take screen shot using ASL Library instead of rooting the device. And then it will be run on service...Do you have any idea for this ...if u have source code Please send me. But my app is capturing the application view not phone view. i need to take on phone view. My code is given below here. and describe the steps for using asl library in project

my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and then i replaced also....

```
public void captureScreen(long ImageNum) 
{       
   View v=getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);    
   //findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();      
   v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   bitmap  = v1.getDrawingCache();
   saveBitmap(bitmap,counter1);        
}
```

but same answer only got it.kindly help me.Thanks in advance